# How to pass setter value directly to web page (thymeleaf)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, usb, thymeleaf

I am using **spring boot mvc**. I have a **usb reader** which reads and sets a value to the **setID(String id)** method of a **User-Model**. Now i need to print this setter value in the web page **issueCard.html**. But i find it difficult how to pass this setter value to the page.

Comment: Don't you also have a `getId()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your setter method sets the value of a field on your model. You need a *getter* for that field, for Thymeleaf to *get* it.

So if your model class would be like this...

```
package hello;

public class UsbReader {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And your controller like this...

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class UsbReaderController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String usbReaderPage(Model model) {
        UsbReader usbReader = new UsbReader();
        usbReader.setId("test");
        model.addAttribute("usbReader", usbReader);
        return "issueCard";
    }
}
```

Then you would write your template file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <p>
        The ID is: <span th:text="${usbReader.id}"></span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```